# confirming size of decimal(M, D) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to change my float columns to decimals such that the new column supports 4 digits after the decimal point and occupies 8 bytes.  After reading the mysql documentation I believe that decimal(17, 4) should work but I am having trouble confirming this.  I have tried looking at data_length from information_schema but it looks like storage is allocated in chunks.  Is there a way of doing a sizeof(column) in mysql?

Edit: I am not sure why this is marked as a duplicated. As I stated earlier, I have read the mysql documentation (and searched btw). It is based on this that I believe that decimal(17, 4) will satisfy my requirements. I am looking for a way to confirm the actual storage in my dev enivronment before I change several million rows in production. As to why 8 bytes, I like defining data like this on word boundaries as I've seen significant performance improvements in other applications. I don't know if it makes a difference with mysql but I doubt it will hurt. Decimal(17,4) is sufficiently large and precise for my application.

Comment: :) SEARCH and ye shall find

Comment: Or [Look](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) and ye shall see

Comment: Why the requirement for 8 bytes? Generally column sizing is based on the data that is going to fill it, not the size it will take on disk.